# What is "&#xD2B9;&#xC218;" this kind of character and how can I hande this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl some web site like below:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                "특수"
                <br>
                "처리"
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I am having some troubles.

When I try to print the result, it prints "특수처리".

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);

// ...

const text = $(this).find('td').text()
console.log(text)
```

What I want is "특수 처리", or "특수\n처리".
Anyway, I want to split "특수" and "처리".

So I realize that I should use `html()` instead of `text()`.
But it prints the wrong string like `"&#xD2B9;&#xC218;"`.

How can I use this?
Somebody help me please?

Comment: [HTML entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Comment: You should use the actual code and not an arbitrary `Hello World`, because for `Hello World` you won't get `&#xD2B9;&#xC218;` as a result. And `&#xD2B9;&#xC218;` is your problem. So if `$(this).find('td').text()` results in `&#xD2B9;&#xC218;`  then you should show the code that allows to reproduce that.